# javaFX Load Exception and javaFX Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, weather-api

I'm trying to launch a small, quickly-made weather application and i'm receiving errors that several hours of googling can't help me solve. I've seen similar reports, but the core issues i'm facing seem to be around two bits of code:

```
public void setTemperature() {
    getTemperatureField().setText(weather.getCurrentTemp() + "° F");
}
```

and

```
else {
        //didn't have a default image, so chose one at random
        getWeatherIcon().setImage(this.rainy);
    }
```

Now, I can see that the two bits of code are similar. Both are trying to modify elements of sample.fxml, and both are failing with NPE's.

What am I missing? My goal is to be able to use the information I pull from the DarkSkies API in my Weather.java class to *set* the weatherIcon Image and the Temperature text, but that doesn't seem possible.

Any tips and help would be great, Thanks a bunch guys and gals.

#### *WeatherController.java*

```
package sample;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class WeatherController {

    public WeatherController() {
        weather = gson.fromJson(weather.getDarkSkyResponse(), Weather.class);
        setWeatherIcon();
        setTemperature();
    }

    //Instance variables for images
    Weather weather = new Weather();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    @FXML private ImageView weatherIcon;
    @FXML private TextField temperatureField;
    Image sunny = new Image("images/sunny.png");
    Image rainy = new Image("images/rain.png");
    Image snowy = new Image("images/snow.png");
    Image cloudy = new Image("images/cloudy.png");
    Image partlyCloudy = new Image("images/partly_cloudy.png");
    Image chanceOfRain = new Image("images/chance_of_rain.png");
    Image chanceOfSnow = new Image("images/chance_of_snow.png");
    Image stormy = new Image("images/storm.png");
    Image thunderStorm = new Image("images/thunderstorm.png");

    public ImageView getWeatherIcon() {
        return this.weatherIcon;
    }

    public TextField getTemperatureField() {
        return this.temperatureField;
    }

    public void theButtonClick() {
        System.out.println("You clicked the button");
    } 

    public void setWeatherIcon() {
        String weatherType = (String)weather.getCurrentIcon();
        if (weatherType == "clear-day" || weatherType == "clear-night") {
            getWeatherIcon().setImage(this.sunny);
        }
        if (weatherType == "rain") {
            getWeatherIcon().setImage(this.rainy);
        }
        if (weatherType == "snow" || weatherType == "sleet") {
            getWeatherIcon().setImage(this.snowy);
        }
        if (weatherType == "cloudy") {
            getWeatherIcon().setImage(this.cloudy);
        }
        if (weatherType == "partly-cloudy-day") {
            getWeatherIcon().setImage(this.partlyCloudy);
        }
        else {
            //didn't have a default image, so chose one at random
            getWeatherIcon().setImage(this.rainy);
        }
    }

    public void setTemperature() {
        getTemperatureField().setText(weather.getCurrentTemp() + "° F");
    }

    public void printCurrentTemp() {
        System.out.println("Current temperature is: " + weather.getCurrentTemp() + "° F");
    }
}
```

#### *Weather.java*

```
package sample;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Weather {

/* Instance Variables */
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String darkSkyURL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[insert my key here]/";

/* Maps for each type of weather response */
private HashMap<String, Object> currently = new HashMap();
private HashMap<String, Object> minutely = new HashMap();
//private HashMap<String, Object> hourly = new HashMap();
//private HashMap<String, Object> daily = new HashMap();
//private HashMap<String, Object> alerts = new HashMap();

/* CONSTRUCTOR */
public Weather() {
    setLatitude(138.176374);
    setLongitude(-83.438066);
    setDarkSkyURL();
    populateFields();
}


/* SETTERS */
public void setLatitude(double lat) { this.latitude = lat; }
public void setLongitude(double lon) { this.longitude = lon; }
public void setDarkSkyURL() {
    darkSkyURL = getDarkSkyURL() + getLatitude() + "," + getLongitude();
}


/* GETTERS */
public double getLatitude() { return this.latitude; }
public double getLongitude() { return this.longitude; }
public String getDarkSkyURL() { return this.darkSkyURL; }

/* GETTERS FOR HASHMAP "CURRENTLY" */
public Object getCurrentTime() { return this.currently.get("time"); }
public Object getCurrentSummary() { return this.currently.get("summary"); }
public Object getCurrentIcon() { return this.currently.get("icon"); }
public Object getCurrentNearestStormDistance() { return this.currently.get("nearestStormDistance"); }
public Object getCurrentPrecipIntensity() { return this.currently.get("precipIntensity"); }
public Object getCurrentlyPrecipProbability() { return this.currently.get("precipProbability"); }
public Object getCurrentTemp() { return this.currently.get("temperature"); }
public Object getCurrentApparentTemp() { return this.currently.get("apparentTemperature"); }
public Object getCurrentDewPoint() { return this.currently.get("dewPoint"); }
public Object getCurrentHumidity() { return this.currently.get("humidity"); }
public Object getCurrentWindSpeed() { return this.currently.get("windSpeed"); }
public Object getCurrentWindBearing() { return this.currently.get("windBearing"); }
public Object getCurrentVisibility() { return this.currently.get("visibility"); }
public Object getCurrentCloudCover() { return this.currently.get("cloudCover"); }
public Object getCurrentPressure() { return this.currently.get("pressure"); }
public Object getCurrentOzone() { return this.currently.get("ozone"); }

/* GETTERS FOR HASHMAP MINUTELY */
public Object getMinutelySummary() { return this.minutely.get("summary"); }
public Object getMinutelyIcon() { return this.minutely.get("icon"); }
public Object getMinutelyTime() { return this.minutely.get("time"); }
public Object getMinutelyPrecipIntensity() { return this.minutely.get("precipIntensity"); }
public Object getMinutelyPrecipProbability() { return this.minutely.get("precipProbability"); }
public Object getMinutelyPrecipType() { return this.minutely.get("precipType"); }

/* DARK SKY FORECAST RETRIEVAL */
public String getDarkSkyResponse() {
    String fullResponse = "";
    try {
        URL darkSkyTarget = new URL(getDarkSkyURL());
        URLConnection dsConnection = darkSkyTarget.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dsConnection.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            fullResponse += inputLine;
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("new URL failed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("openConnection failed");
    }

    return fullResponse;
}

private void populateFields() {
    populateCurrently();
    populateMinutely();

}

public void populateCurrently() {
    currently.put("time", 0);
    currently.put("summary", "");
    currently.put("icon", "");
    currently.put("nearestStormDistance", 0);
    currently.put("precipIntensity", 0.0);
    currently.put("precipProbability", 0);
    currently.put("precipType", "");
    currently.put("temperature", 0.0);
    currently.put("apparentTemperature", 0.0);
    currently.put("dewPoint", 0.0);
    currently.put("humidity", 0.0);
    currently.put("windSpeed", 0.0);
    currently.put("windBearing", 0);
    currently.put("visibility", 0.0);
    currently.put("cloudCover", 0.0);
    currently.put("pressure", 0.0);
    currently.put("ozone", 0.0);
}

public void populateMinutely() {
    minutely.put("summary", "");
    minutely.put("icon", "");
    minutely.put("time", 0);
    minutely.put("precipIntensity", 0.0);
    minutely.put("precipProbability", 0);
    minutely.put("precipType", "");
}
```

}

#### *Main.java*

```
package sample;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Weatherly");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 480, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

#### *sample.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?scenebuilder-background-color 0x99f3ffff?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="480.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="sample.WeatherController">
  <children>
    <BorderPane layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="480.0">
      <bottom>
        <HBox prefHeight="133.0" prefWidth="480.0">
          <children>
            <Button fx:id="theButton" maxWidth="-1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 20px;&#10;&#10;" text="Button" textAlignment="CENTER">
              <HBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="165.0" top="10.0" />
              </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
          </children>
        </HBox>
      </bottom>
      <center>
        <VBox prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
          <children>
            <TextField id="locationField" alignment="CENTER" editable="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="310.0" promptText="City, State" style="-fx-font-family: &quot;Verdana&quot;;&#10;-fx-font-size: 18px;&#10;-fx-font-weight: bold;&#10;&#10;&#10;" text="">
              <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" top="120.0" />
              </VBox.margin>
            </TextField>
            <ImageView fx:id="weatherIcon" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" smooth="true" y="0.0">
              <image>
                <Image url="@../../images/sunny.png" />
              </image>
              <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="55.0" right="55.0" top="10.0" />
              </VBox.margin>
            </ImageView>
            <TextField fx:id="temperatureField" alignment="CENTER" editable="false" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Temp" style="-fx-font-family: &quot;Tahoma&quot;;&#10;-fx-font-size: 24px;&#10;-fx-font-weight: bold;&#10;" text="">
              <VBox.margin>
                <Insets left="80.0" top="10.0" />
              </VBox.margin>
            </TextField>
          </children>
        </VBox>
      </center>
      <left>
        <Pane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="83.0" />
      </left>
      <right>
        <Pane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="87.0" />
      </right>
      <top>
        <MenuBar>
          <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
      </top>
    </BorderPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

#### *The Error Report*

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Users\LibStaff\Desktop\IntelliJ\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\Computer Science\Java\Weatherly\out\production\Weatherly;C:\Users\LibStaff\Desktop\gson-master\gson\target\gson-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\LibStaff\Desktop\IntelliJ\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain sample.Main
    Exception in Application start method
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/Computer%20Science/Java/Weatherly/out/production/Weatherly/sample/sample.fxml:13

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:17)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.WeatherController.setWeatherIcon(WeatherController.java:64)
    at sample.WeatherController.<init>(WeatherController.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: most likely `../../images/sunny.png` is not at the expected location. Are you running your project from an IDE? If so: which?

Comment: Yes, I am, IntelliJ. Why would sunny not be in the correct location? I didn't see any errors with that image file. Thank you for the response!

Comment: because the *working directory" at runtime of your app ist the IDEs target folder (Eclipse names it `bin` by default, IntelliJ baybe too...) So what you should do is to declare the folder `images` to be a (re-)source folder in your project and refer to it without the "back steps", just `images/sunny.png`.